# Displaying images on Amazon's API Gateway for S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I've got an jpeg image stored in a bucket using Amazon S3. I've followed this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html) roughly to setup a REST API as an Amazon S3 Proxy in API Gateway. I'm using this API endpoint as way to access the images stored in the bucket using a GET request. I've also followed along with this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html) that provides insight in enabling binary support. When I do a GET request at the given endpoint of the image, I want the image to show. The problem is that even following that guide, it doesn't work. The image doesn't show properly and I'm left with some junk: [image]

Does anyone have any insight on this issue or a way they enabled binary support on their API endpoints?

Comment: Looks like response headers are messed up. Guide you are referring to deals with json/text files. Make sure your Content-type header in the response is matching the type of the file you are returning, such as image/jpeg.

Comment: @Anton Is this what you're [referring to?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html). I've setup it like that but nothing changes